# Django data is not being stored on Postgres Db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

Up until January, my Django app was saving data to this DB but now it is not working.
The migrations pass and declare ok on the CLI but it doesn't get saved in the DB.

It still works with SQLite3 DB but I get this error

> {
> "error": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'"
> }

I did not make any big change to the settings prior to this

Comment: It seems like there is no issue with Database as it's splitting issue. Maybe this is ORM issue. Try using django shell to test and insert data (Eg. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-orm-inserting-updating-deleting-data/) or send more stack trace here.

Comment: @VinayDavda I just Created and Read data from the Shell and it worked fine

Comment: Are you able to manually regenerate this issue ? If yes you can put a debug point at issue and execute line by line. It should help.

Comment: @VinayDavda that's the issue, for Postgres everything runs and it returns status code  201 even though nothing was added to the DB, it does not throw any error

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Sqlite as you described in question ? Also check whether you after january have you updated django version or postgres version or any other dependany python modules.

Comment: @VinayDavda I'm using SQLite3 on Local host and Postgres on production, No I did not but I'm going to try that now

Comment: this is error is { "error": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'" } is from the email sending function  @VinayDavda

Comment: Have you used rsplit() in your function ? if yes then object before rsplit might have None value. Eg. `mail_data.rsplit(',')` it's possible that here mail_data is `None`. Try printing mail_data or update condition to handle this case.

Comment: @VinayDavda No I did not, It is working perfectly for localhost ... same issue on production

Comment: Can you send that line or function here in question, so I can suggest better

Comment: @VinayDavda  that line is already solved except you mean another one